# Как создать OpenAPI для сайта?

Tags: javascript, java, mysql

Я выполняю следующую задачу. На моём сайте в БД (MySQL) находится информация. Я хочу, чтобы владельцы других сайтов могли импортировать эту информацию на свой сайт с помощью JavaScript ( как у FaceBook и Вконтакте).

Разработчик будет вставлять в head

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="api/share.js" charset="windows-1251"></script>
</head>
```

и блог с информацией в любое место на сайте.

Подскажите, есть ли пособия, в которых описывается как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что вы хотите реализовать является по сути [RPC](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Procedure_Call)
Для начала вам следует определится с протоколом обмена.

Учитывая, что вам необходимо предоставлять доступ к данным со своего сайта для других сайтов, то стоит ознакомится со [способами кросс-доменого обмена данными](http://javascript.ru/ajax/cross-domain-scripting)
Я бы например выбрал в качестве формата сообщений [JSONP(P)](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP_.26_JSONPP) за его легкость подключение и универсальность.
Так же стоит посмотреть на решения используемые другими сайтами(GoogleMaps, Vkontakte, etc), и проанализировать.

Следующим шагом надо написать достаточно несложную библиотеку, с помощью которой вы могли бы регистрировать для внешних команд, какие функции у вас должны выполнятся, и что принимать/возвращать.
Это обеспечит легкую расширяемость вашего API.

Comment: PS
charset="windows-1251" - Далеко не лучшая идея для OpenAPI
как только вы решите, что ваш сервис может работать не только с русским языком, но и с другими, у существующих клиентов начнутся проблемы, впрочем как и у вас

Answer (score 0):

почему бы просто не давать возможность пользователям API задавать кодировку?